# jQuery removeClass re-renders video player in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jwplayer

I have this most annoying issue with `removeClass` in Firefox. 
I am using it to change some of the elements on the page so that when I resize my player the layout looks good. I am using JW player API to resize the player using the jQuery click method, then it starts playing automatically or from the position it was at.

Now all of that works perfectly in IE (surprising), Chrome, Opera, Safari. It's seemless with no hiccup. But Firefox will reinitialize the player and it starts over. I have a `removeClass` that I perform on a div that surrounds the player. If I take that out, Firefox does what it's supposed to do. I have to use the `removeClass` to realign my layout. It works fine with `addClass`, just not with `removeClass`.

Any ideas why it won't work with `removeClass()` properly?
Below is my code how I want it to work and it does for EVERY browser but FF.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
jQuery("#expand").live("click",function(event){
  var time = jwplayer().getPosition();
  var cont = $('#lcontents').html();
   $('#tleft').html(cont);
   $('#pleft').addClass("centerText videoWide");
   $('#pleft').removeClass("column-video-left"); 
   $('#lcontents').html("");
   $('#tleft').addClass("column-video-left");

   jwplayer().resize("854","480");
    if(time > 0){
        jwplayer().onReady(function() {             
            jwplayer().seek(time);          
        });
    }else if(time < 1){ 
        jwplayer().play();
    };
event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Edit- The code below is the html

```
<div id="pleft" class="column-video-left">
    <div id="rsplayer" class="video">jwplayer code renders here</div>
    <div id="expand" style="text-align:center"><a href="#">Expand Player</a></div>
    <div id="lcontents">
            regular html code here.... which gets moved to div tleft
    </div>
</div>
<div id="expand1"></div>
<div id="tleft"></div>
```

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your problem. I've setup [a test page](http://brian.peiris.name/so/5371285/) that seems to work perfectly on all the browsers and OS's I've tested. Does the problem occur because you are using an HTML5 player? If not, what version of Flash are you running? What OS are you running? Can you reproduce the problem on a publicly-accessible site?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually modify the class attribute and seeing if that works?

Comment: @Pjack: e.g., using Firebug (just double-click the class name).

Comment: Gotcha. Nope, if you manually remove the class usig firebug while its playing it stops the player and reinitiates. But if you manually add the classes I want, it makes the changes but keeps playing. Im using ff 3.6.15. That sux.

Comment: Agreed. Have you tried using any other attributes (id/name/etc.) as your selector instead and see if it still causes the element to reload?

Comment: Firebug probably does roughly the same thing jQuery does. You could also try using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList) (which IIRC is not cross-browser, so you can't use it in production) and see if that has the same effect. Just as another data point.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible this is a known bug in Firefox 3.6. You could try it in the Firefox 4 release candidate and see if you still have the same problem. If you don't, then someone who's good at doing Bugzilla searches could figure out what the bug was, and whether the fix will be backported to the 3.6 branch.